# elasticsearch compression optimization

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using logstash and shipping to elasticsearch.

Have anyone optimized the storage in ES? Would there be a way to increase the compression so it's closer to a logrotate/syslog storage in terms of size

Comment: I'm not as familiar with ElasticSearch, but I notice it's somewhat difficult to find detailed documentation about their `_source` compression (perhaps it's supposed to "just work"). ES enables compression by default since v0.90. Best I've found is to reduce the amount of duplicate information stored, for example by stripping a field that's been parsed into multiple pieces.

Comment: Removing the message field alone should cut down your ES index size by quite a bit. You should also remove any other fields you don't need before you store your data in ES.